# jQuery + Rails returns correct column, but then entire record

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

The intent of the following code is to create a paragraph element containing the dimension_version name of every dimension's dimension version.

```
$("#dave").html("<%= Dimension.find(params[:id]).dimension_versions.each do |dv| %><p><%= dv.name %></p><% end %>");
```

This actually results in the expected behavior, but is followed by the entire record for each dimension version returned, which is unexpected:

```
Default
Test 1
[#<DimensionVersion id: 3, name: "Default", dimension_id: 2, created_at: "2013-02-01 15:04:05", updated_at: "2013-02-01 15:04:05">, #<DimensionVersion id: 10, name: "Test 1", dimension_id: 2, created_at: "2013-02-01 16:03:55", updated_at: "2013-02-01 16:03:55">]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to remove the = from <%=. So this:

```
$("#dave").html("**<%=** Dimension.find(params[:id]).dimension_versions.each do |dv| %><p><%= dv.name %></p><% end %>");
```

Became:

```
$("#dave").html("**<%** Dimension.find(params[:id]).dimension_versions.each do |dv| %><p><%= dv.name %></p><% end %>");
```

Comment: Glad you found by yourself :)

Comment: Do accept your answer. So that it doesn't counted to be an unanswered question. :)

Comment: I have to wait two days. Thanks for the heads up!